Discrepancies in a solution to a question on probability theory.

In a TV show, a contestant opts to video call a friend as a life-line. He has to choose from one of the three - Akbar, Amar, and Anthony. The question which he asks from them has four options. Find the probability that Akbar couldn't give the correct answer.

This is a question asked in a Specimen Paper of the ICSE examination held in India for grade ten students. I got $\frac{1}{4}$ as the solution through the method that I detail below -
Assume 6 cases to be possible: Akbar gets chosen and gives an incorrect answer, Akbar gets chosen and gives the correct answer, Amar gets chosen and gives an incorrect answer, Amar gets chosen and gives the correct answer, Anthony gets chosen and gives an incorrect answer, Anthony gets chosen and gives the correct answer.
Then, total no. of outcomes = 12 (3 each for incorrect answers + 1 each for correct answer.)
No. of outcomes where Akbar gave the incorrect answer = 3
Therefore probability of him giving an incorrect answer = $\frac{3}{12}$ = $\frac{1}{4}$
However, the solution in the paper was given to be $\frac{3}{4}$
Therefore, I want to know whether I have committed some error while calculating the probability, and if not, which answer is more appropriate/correct?
Thanks,
a math nerd.

You also have to add the no. of outcomes where Amar and Anthony give incorrect answers.

Well, the problem asks for the probability that he "couldn't give the correct answer"   which I'd say included the cases in which he simply was not asked.   In particular, it is different from asking "what is the probability that he gave an incorrect answer".  That said, adding those cases does not give the answer $\frac 34$.

Should say:  the problem is very vaguely worded.  I suppose we are to guess that the call is placed to a person uniformly at random and that whoever is called simply guesses the answer uniformly at random.  Of course, that's not how these games work, at all.  Fine to simplify things for a math problem, but then the problem should explicitly state the assumptions.

@lulu: My thoughts exactly. OP, is the quoted wording verbatim from the paper? My first impression is that there isn't nearly enough information in the question.

Yes, there were some grammatical errors in the statement itself that I fixed, but no other information was stated. I'll link the Specimen Paper below if anyone wanted to verify - https://cisce.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/ICSE_2025_SPECIMEN_QP_MS_511_MAT.pdf

The question is ill posed because we have no information about Akbar knowing the answer or not.
The answer of $3/4$ is correct only if Akbar has absolutely no idea about the correct answer
The question of Akbar giving a right or wrong answer arises only if he is the friend chosen to answer.
In other words, we are asked the conditional probability
P(Akbar gives wrong answer| he was asked to answer) and the answer is $3/4$ with the proviso mentioned in the second paragraph.

Agree with the interpretation, although slight nitpick that if Akbar doesn't know the answer, his chance of getting it right is 1/4 regardless of how he chooses (assuming no information about how the answer is distributed). He need not pick an answer uniformly or at random, in the long run of many imagined trials, his chance of being right is 1/4 even if we know that Akbar always chooses "Answer 1" regardless of what he's asked. You can use any strategy you want to call a series of coin flips (always heads, always tails, or a mix), and you'll always expect to get 50% of them right.

@NuclearHoagie: Okay, the terminological inexactitude has been removed.

I suppose considering the cases in which Akbar isn't picked to answer the question is the flaw in my method? Is that what you're alluding to?

Yes, only the chosen friend can answer

On that note, were the question framed like, "Calculate the probability that Akbar gives a wrong answer.", would the other cases where Anthony and Amar were chosen to give the answer still not considered? And if yes, why not? Wouldn't these cases where he was not asked also factor into the calculation of the probability?

On the assumption that none of them have any idea of the correct answer, and are answering independently, each of them would individually have $Pr = \frac34$ of giving a wrong answer,  It is only of you start asking questions like Pr(all give wrong answers) $= \frac{27}{64}$, or Pr(at least one gives a right answer) $=\frac{37}{64}$,  that all of them start coming into the computations.
